# entering password into openssl command from shell script

Tags: shell, openssl, sh, piping

I am trying to convert a p12 to a pem from a shell script without any user input. 
I can have the password as a variable within the script.

so when I call:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in *.p12 -out cert.pem -nodes
```

The terminal prints "Enter Import Password:" and waits for input.

I tried to pipe the password in with:

```
echo $PASS | openssl pkcs12 -in *.p12 -out cert.pem -nodes
```

as well as trying to use a flag with the openssl command but can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: What flag did you try?

Comment: Add `-passin pass:12345678` to line

Comment: Thanks. I thought passin would only take a file as input...But I got it work with -password stdin, so openssl expects the password to come from stdin, then the pipe work.

Answer (score 7):

This one liner worked for me-

```
openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.p12 -password pass:<your_password> -nodes | openssl x509 -noout -enddate
```

Comment: You saved me, I was putting the password at the end of the line near the `-enddate`, but it should be before the pipe when opening the certificate.
Note that new command is `-passin` instead of `password` as indicated above.